# Multiple react components on a page connected as Portals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm just starting out with React and I have a bit of a architecture/conceptual question.

I have a use case where I have multiple React components on a page, but the page itself is not a React app. Imagine for example product purchase buttons, a cart button with the count of products, some product presentation modules, a checkout module, etc.;

Essentially most of these components should be aware of a shared global state, e.g. is a product in the cart, how many products are there in the cart, etc.

Conceptually, I am wondering if I can use Portals to link all components on the page together under an app without anything rendered in the app’s root element, or if this is not how Portals are intended. Basically, I have a app root which is just an empty element. When the app initializes (after page load) I am scanning for DOM nodes that should represent components, and then create the component as returning nothing but `createPortal` elements on those DOM nodes.

Is this a valid and performant way of managing state across multiple components on a page where the entire page is not a React app per se?

Or should I be adding each component as a standalone root and use some event messaging to connect them all? Or is there an altogether better React solution of doing this?

I'm not looking for code examples, I have the above working. But I am wondering what is the "React-way" to achieve this. Pseudo code is okay of course.

Comment: You can definitely check out microfrontends and module federation as an option to achieve this. You can have the state maintained in your host app and then share it to the react components.